# Binutils 2.29 installation error when attempting to build a Linux distro using “Linux From Scratch” instructions

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, installation, elementaryos

I am attempting to build a Linux distribution with [*Linux From Scratch (LFS) version 8.1*.](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/8.1/) I am building it with [ElementaryOS](https://elementary.io) (which is based on Ubuntu) which I have installed on VirtualBox on my Mac. I have a bit of experience with Linux, so I have an idea of what I’m doing.

Everything was going well until I got to [section 5.4](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/development/chapter05/binutils-pass1.html) in the book. This section instructs how to compile and install [Binutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/) 2.29 (the book instructed me to use version 2.29 since newer versions have not been tested yet for *Linux From Scratch*). Once I got to this part of the book, nothing seemed to go right. Here’s what I did:

Following the book, I prepared to compile it with this command:

```
./configure --prefix=/tools            
         --with-sysroot=$LFS        
         --with-lib-path=/tools/lib 
         --target=$LFS_TGT          
         --disable-nls              
         --disable-werror
```

After I did that I compiled it with `make`. Since I’m working on a 64bit machine and system, I executed this, as instructed, after compiling:

```
case $(uname -m) in
  x86_64) mkdir -v /tools/lib && ln -sv lib /tools/lib64 ;;
esac
```

Then I executed `make install` and this is where I started having issues. Terminal gave me this:

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/media/nathanael/f2f5c607-926f-4931-ba6e-4e4fd6f08eee/build'
/bin/bash ./mkinstalldirs /tools /tools
mkdir -p -- /tools /tools
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/tools’: File exists
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/tools’: File exists
Makefile:2466: recipe for target 'installdirs' failed
make[1]: *** [installdirs] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/media/nathanael/f2f5c607-926f-4931-ba6e-4e4fd6f08eee/build
Makefile:2224: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

I had several issues before getting to this point, thankfully I managed to fix them, but this one baffles me. Any suggestions on what I should do?

I did deviate from the book in one place. The book had me create an unprivileged user called `lfs` which I was supposed to use when compiling (this way, chances of accidentally ruining the system would be low). But I had problems compiling with `lfs`. I tried several things to get it to work but found that just compiling as admin worked the best. Hope that doesn't cause problems in the long run.

Any help would be very greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that the build directory is cluttered.

Try running `make clean`.

Comment: Welcome to superuser: While this may or may not answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide more explanation with detail and an easy to follow instructions. Yes your answer may provide an answer to this user but future readers may not understand enough for the answer to be useful. Anyway thanks for the answer.  Please take a couple of minutes and read:- http://superuser.com/help .Answering: http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer, again welcome to superuser and keep answering. Thankyou

Comment: If I run `make clean` will I have to compile it again? If I remember right, `make clean`will clean up the directory alright, but would require me to recompile the package again. I'll give it a try.